# Puppet Split function fails

Tags: puppet

**Problem**

Puppet split function fails since Puppet has been upgraded puppet to version `3.5.1`, while this worked until `3.4.3`

**Code**

```
 1  $ports_regex = "80\\|443"
 2
 3  $ports_string       = regsubst($ports_regex, '\\\|', ',', 'G')
 4
 5  notify{"CP1 ${ports_string}":}
 6
 7  $ports_array = split($ports_string, ',')
 8
 9  notify{"CP2 ${ports_array}":}
10
11  each($ports_array) |$port| {
12      notify{"CP3 ${port}":}
13
14      file {"${port}":
15          path => "c:/temp/puppettest/${port}",
16          ensure => present;
17      }
18  }
```

**Outcome**

3.4.3

```
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[443]/ensure: created
Notice: CP2 80443
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Notify[CP2 80443]/message: defined 'message' as 'CP2 80443'
Notice: CP1 80,443
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Notify[CP1 80,443]/message: defined 'message' as 'CP1 80,443'
Notice: CP3 80
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Notify[CP3 80]/message: defined 'message' as 'CP3 80'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/File[80]/ensure: created
Notice: CP3 443
Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Notify[CP3 443]/message: defined 'message' as 'CP3 443'
```

3.5.1

```
C:\Windows\system32>puppet apply --parser future --debug --verbose "C:\temp\puppettest\site.pp"
Error: Invalid tag cp2  at C:/temp/puppettest/site.pp:9 on node ...
Error: Invalid tag cp2  at C:/temp/puppettest/site.pp:9 on node ...
```

**Question**

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can we get some line numbers here?  What exactly is on line 9 of your site.pp?  Is line 9 the split() call?

Comment: I have added line numbers as well

Comment: It may be a regression in the future parser. You may wish to bring this up with the dev team.

Comment: It seems that the split function neither works in 3.5.1, nor in 3.6.0. [An issue](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-2612) has been created at Puppet Labs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ticket closed and marked as "won't fix", see https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-2612

> Henrik Lindberg added a comment - 2014/05/19 3:43 PM - edited
>
> Ah, the next issue is that interpolation of hashes and arrays produce
> their source equivalent text where it used to just run all the content
> together.
>
> You can see that if you compare the following with the current and
> future parsers:
>
> $a = [1,2,3]
>
> notice $a
>
> notice "$a"
>
> I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here - the original seems
> to have created "CP 2 80443", and you now get "CP2 [80, 443]" which it
> then barfs on. Then when you iterate of $ports_array, you will get a
> $port that is first 80 and then 443 (when the regexp has been
> corrected with 6 backslashes). This means you put 2 notify in the
> catalog; "CP3 80", and then "CP3 443", and then creates 2 file
> resources, one titled "80", and then one titled "443".
>
> The Resource implementation is responsible for the interpretation of
> the title string, and it does odd things when facing punctuation,
> spaces, numbers and brackets.
>
> Tip is to use notice to get output with intermediate results. I used
> this for the first part:
>
> $ports_regex = "80\|443"
>
> $ports_string = regsubst($ports_regex, '\\\|', ',', 'G')
>
> notice "ports_regex = '${ports_regex}'"
>
> notice "ports_string = '${ports_string}'"
>
> $ports_array = split($ports_string, ',')
>
> notice "ports_array = '${ports_array}'"
>
> $a = "CP1 ${ports_string}"
>
> notice $a
>
> notify{$a:}
>
> $b = "CP2 ${ports_array}"
>
> notice $b
>
> notify{$b:}
>
> If you want the old behavior of simply running all the content of the
> array together into one string without any separators, you should use
> the join function in stdlib (i.e. join($ports_array, ''), but then you
> could just do that with a separate substitute of the commas.
>
> You can also do this in a different order - something like:
>
> $ports_array = $ports_regex.split('\\\|')
>
> $ports_string = $ports_array.join('')
>
> The first splits the string into an array, and the second constructs a
> string with the numbers joined without punctuation and brackets. You
> can then use that string to interpolate into the titles starting with
> CP.
>
> Or if you do not want to type so many backslashes, you can use a
> regexp directly:
>
> $ports_array = $ports_regex.split(/\|/)
>
> $ports_string = $ports_array.join('')
>
> Hope that helps